# How to modify code to add a quit option in the menu and keep it looping until it is called?

Tags: java, loops, oop

I am working on a Java text-based adventure game and want to change my code to add a Quit option as a fourth item and keep it looping until the user chooses to quit based on the respective choice. I originally had it so that it would run 10 times inside a while loop, but I decided I wanted the user to have control when they want to quit and end the program.

Here is what I have so far:

**Game.java**

```
public class Game {
    private static Room library, study, ballroom, kitchen;
    private static Room currentLocation;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       initialSetupGame();
       int rounds = 10;
       while(rounds > 0) {
          printNextRooms();
          int nextRoomIndex = getUserRoomChoice();
          Room nextRoom = getNextRoom(nextRoomIndex);
          updateRoom(nextRoom);
          rounds--;
       }
    }

    public static void initialSetupGame() {
        // Instantiate room objects of type Room
        library = new Room("Library");
        study = new Room("Study");
        ballroom = new Room("Ballroom");
        kitchen = new Room("Kitchen");

        // Connect the objects to each other
        library.addConnectedRoom(study);
        library.addConnectedRoom(ballroom);
        library.addConnectedRoom(kitchen);

        study.addConnectedRoom(library);
        study.addConnectedRoom(ballroom);
        study.addConnectedRoom(kitchen);

        ballroom.addConnectedRoom(library);
        ballroom.addConnectedRoom(study);
        ballroom.addConnectedRoom(kitchen);

        kitchen.addConnectedRoom(library);
        kitchen.addConnectedRoom(ballroom);
        kitchen.addConnectedRoom(study);

        // Prompt user for a name
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
        String playerName = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println(playerName + "? Wow, that's a neat name!"
                + "\nWelcome to Aether Paradise, a game where you can explore"
                + " the the majestic hidden rooms of Aether. Let's begin!");

        // Set the player to start in the library
        currentLocation = library;
        System.out.println(currentLocation.getDescription());

    }
    public static void printNextRooms() {
        // Lists room objects as menu items
        System.out.println("Where would you like to go next?");
        currentLocation.printListOfNamesOfConnectedRooms();
    }

    public static int getUserRoomChoice() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("{Select a number): ");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        return choice - 1;
    }
    public static Room getNextRoom(int index) {
        return currentLocation.getConnectedRoom(index);
    }
    public static void updateRoom(Room newRoom) {
        currentLocation = newRoom;
        System.out.println(currentLocation.getDescription());
    }
}
```

**Room.java**

```
public class Room {
private String name;
private String description;
private ArrayList<Room> connectedRooms;

public Room(String roomName) {
    this.name = roomName;
    this.description = "";
    connectedRooms = new ArrayList<>();
}

public Room(String roomName, String roomDescription) {
    this.name = roomName;
    this.description = roomDescription;
    connectedRooms = new ArrayList<>();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

// Add connected room to the array list
public void addConnectedRoom(Room connectedRoom) {
    connectedRooms.add(connectedRoom);
}

public Room getConnectedRoom(int index) {
   return connectedRooms.get(index);
}

public int getNumberOfConnectedRooms() {
    return connectedRooms.size();
}
// Print the connected rooms to the console
public void printListOfNamesOfConnectedRooms() {
    for(int index = 0; index < connectedRooms.size(); index++) {
        Room r = connectedRooms.get(index);
        String n = r.getName();
        System.out.println((index + 1) + ". " + n);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This type of question is usually too general for Stack Overflow. You're essentially asking us to write a part of your program. Stack Overflow was made for very specific problems, like debugging a specific error that you are getting.

Comment: I see. Thanks for letting me know. I was just very stumped and don't have an opportunity to get help from my professor or the university tutoring center because of this whole pandemic. I was essentially let loose to do a final project on my own. But thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `java.util.Scanner` to read input and check the entered value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    initialSetupGame();
    String reply;
    do {
        printNextRooms();
        int nextRoomIndex = getUserRoomChoice();
        Room nextRoom = getNextRoom(nextRoomIndex);
        updateRoom(nextRoom);
        System.out.print("Would you like to continue? [Y]es/[N]o");
        reply = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    } while ('y' == reply.charAt(0));
}
```